# why are orientdb index sizes on disk so large

Tags: orientdb

orientdb 2.0.5

I have a database in which we create non-unque index on 2 properties on a class called indexstat.

The two properties which make up the index are a string identifier plus a long timestamp.

Data is created in batches of few hundred records every 5 minutes.  After a few hours old records are deleted.

This is file listing are the files related to that table.

Question:
Why is the .irs file which according to documentation (is related to non-unique indexes)...so monstrously huge after a few hours. 298056704 bytes larger than actual data (.irs size - .sbt size - .cpm size).

I would think the index would be smaller than the actual data.

Second question:
What is best practice here.  Should I be using unique indexes instead of non-unique?  Should I find a way to make the data in the index smaller (e.g. use longs instead of strings as identifiers)?

Below are file names and the sizes of each.

```
indexstat.cpm 727778304
indexstatidx.irs 1799095296 
indexstatidx.sbt 263168 
indexstat.pcl 773260288
```

This is repeated for a few tables where the index size is larger than the database data.

Answer (score 1):

Internals of *.irs files organised in a such way that when you delete something from an index there is an unused hole left in the file. At some point, when about a half of the file space is wasted, those unused holes come into play again and become available for reuse and allocation. That is done for performance reasons to lower the index data fragmentation. In your case this means that sooner or later the *.irs file will stop growing, and its maximum size should be around 2-3 times larger than the  maximum observed size of the corresponding *.pcl file, assuming your single stat record size is not much bigger compared to the size of the id-timestamp pair size.

Regarding the second question, in a long run it is almost always better to use the most specific/strict data types to model the data and the most specific/strict index types to index it.

Answer (score 0):

At this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/SBMxmWoKxBE) is shown a discussion relative to the index file, maybe can help you.

For the second question, the index should be chosen according to your purpose and your data (not vice versa). The data type (long, string) must be the one that best represents your fields (and already here if for example if you just an integer and this is sufficient to the scope, it is useless to use a long). The same choice for the index, if you need to not have duplicate the choice will be non-unique. if you need an index that allows to choose the range sb-tree instead of the hash and so on ...